# How can I apply css code exception -webkit-scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, display

I execute below code because I want to show only class something's scrollbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar:not(.something){
  display: none;
}
```

(class something's scrollbar is madeby css , overflow-x:scroll)
but when I execute this code, every scrollbar display..
Help me..

Comment: Please include a [example]

Comment: I fix it! I seperate code as 
 .something.current::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: block;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}